# Hindu Marriage - THAALI

Tags: marriage

Is it bad if the husband puts the thaali on the wife's neck multiple times during marriage because the wife likes to only wear the thaali for auspicious occasions.

Just to make it clear, it's always the same husband putting the thaali on the same wife.
I think sometimes in Hinduism, people say odd numbers are bad or something, So is it bad if your husband put the thaali on you 15 times for example?

Answer (score 2):

The Thaali is a symbol which a man ties to his wife's neck to show everyone that he guards her from her head to toe. Not wearing it used to be looked down up on as if it was sacrilege by the woman. But times have changed and people no longer think of it as an important entity, and it is more like an accessory. Some women remove it when going to bed as they find it uncomfortable, and she wears it herself the next day.

But this number of times thing seems to be superstitious, so can't be told as if something wrong might occur.